# data.frame(cbind...) versus data.frame(...) in R

Tags: r

I want to find out what the difference is between the usage of

```
data.frame(a,b,c,y)
```

and

```
data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,y))
```

I have three vectors a,b,c which contain factors (text) and one (y) which stores counts (numbers).

Depending on the notation, I'm getting different answers when I run this model

```
model.glm <- glm(y ~ a * b * c, data=blabla, family=poisson)
```

I guess it's because one of the is making factors "no-factors", but I'm not sure.
Which way is correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, `cbind` returns a `matrix`, which can only have one data type. Mixed data types (e.g. numeric and character) typically get coerced to character. For example:

```
a <- 1:3
b <- c("a", "b", "c")
cb <- cbind(a,b)
cb
     a   b
[1,] "1" "a"
[2,] "2" "b"
[3,] "3" "c"
class(cb)
[1] "matrix"
typeof(cb)
[1] "character"
```

When you pass this into a `data.frame`, by default, characters get converted into factors (`StringsAsFactors = TRUE`; set to `FALSE` to suppress this behavior), which are basically integer representations of strings.

```
df <- data.frame(cb)
typeof(df$a)
[1] "integer"
typeof(df$b)
[1] "integer"
class(df$a)
[1] "factor"
class(df$b)
[1] "factor"
```

I'm assuming this is **not** the behavior you want, and since `data.frame` will nicely `cbind` things for you while maintaining their original types (except for converting strings to factors, which, as I said, can be suppressed), I would stick with the simpler `data.frame(a,b)` construct.

Answer (score 1):

`cbind(a,b,c,y)` returns a matrix that does not allow multiple types of data. So if, say a, b and c are numeric and y is a factor, then `data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,y))` contains only factors.

without `cbind()`, a, b, and c are not converted to factors.

Comment: I read this post out of boredom while some code was executing, and your answer here solved something that was really pissing me off the other day. Good on you, sir!

Comment: Factors are a bad example, since matrices (as far as I can tell) cannot be of class factor. Try `str(data.frame(cbind(3:4,factor(letters[1:2]))))` or `str(matrix(factor(1:4),ncol=2))`

Comment: yes but factors are coerced to characters in matrix. So if  ` a= 1:4` and `b= rep("a",4)` then `cbind(a,b)` contains only characters and `data.frame(a,b)` does not contain the same data as `data.frame(cbind(a,b))`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but this seems incorrect: "`data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,y))` contains only factors"

Comment: you're correct. (at least on my machine), cbind(a,b) contains only character which are all coerced to factors by data.frame() whereas data.frame(a,b) has one column of numeric and one column of factors.